# Count Rows by Group Datatable

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

I have a datatable which is grouped following this scenario.
[Row Grouping](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html)

I want to count rows in every group. Something like this.

```
Group 1 => Total 3 rows

Column 1 || Column 2 || Column 3 || Column 4

Column 1 || Column 2 || Column 3 || Column 4

Column 1 || Column 2 || Column 3 || Column 4

Group 2 => Total 2 rows

Column 1 || Column 2 || Column 3 || Column 4

Column 1 || Column 2 || Column 3 || Column 4
```

How to do this? I already tried [this Solution](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/35847/counting-entries-under-a-grouped-row) but it didn't work.

I think the error is the `groupingCounts[last]`, the table remain shows `loading...` process.

Then, I tried to declare that variable before api.column process.

`var groupingCounts[last] = new Array();`

Nothing changed, the table still display loading process.

Comment: What didn't work? What have you tried so far? Please update your question to avoid downvotes.

Comment: @Michal thanks. I've updated the question